# Call an async function again and again until expected result in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Let's say I have 4 tasks

1. Take a screenshot of a website (using some API service)
2. Download the screenshot to your local hardDrive
3. Upload the screenshot from the local hardDrive to a Google Cloud Bucket
4. Use GC-Vision API to detect text on that screenshot

If the result of task #4 is equal to -1, that means I didn't find what I'm looking for, so I need to do this all over again until the result doesn't equal -1 (which probably means I found what I need).

Now some code:

```
const screenshot = require("./thum/takeScreenshot");
const googleVisionAPI = require("./gc-vision-api/findTextInButton");
const matchURL = /^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$/;
const UploadToGcBucket = require("./gc-storage/saveScreenshot");
const downloadImage = require("./downloadFile");

// let's wait for the bucket to replicate before searching text
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const workHard = async () => {
  // 1. Take a screenshot
  const takeAscreenShot = async () => {
    let scShotTaken = await `https:${screenshot.thumURL}`;
    console.log("screenshot captured!!! ", scShotTaken);
    return scShotTaken;
  };

  //  2. Download it to local hard-drive
  const downloadScreenshot = async url => {
    let download = await downloadImage.downloadImage(url);
    return download;
  };

  // 3. Upload it to Google Cloud Bucket
  const uploadToGCBucket = async () => {
    let upload = await UploadToGcBucket.UploadToGcBucket();
    return upload;
  };

  // 4. Check if the appointment's button is present
  const checkMagicButton = async () => {
    // wait a little bit for replication
    await timeout(5000);

    let searchAppointment = await googleVisionAPI.findMagicButton(
      `some_picture_in_a_cloud_bucket.jpg`
    );
    return searchAppointment;
  };

  takeAscreenShot()
    .then(pic => {
      // Verify if it looks like a URL
      let verifyURL = matchURL.test(pic);

      if (!verifyURL) {
        return "The screenshot doesn't look like a valid URL, check the Thumb API";
      }

      downloadScreenshot(pic)
        .then(() => {
          uploadToGCBucket()
            .then(() => {
              checkMagicButton()
                .then(button => {
                  if (button === -1) {
                    throw new Error();
                  }
                })
                .catch(makeCatch("AI finding button ERROR"));
            })
            .catch(makeCatch("Uploading to GC Bucket ERROR"));
        })
        .catch(makeCatch("Downloading ERROR"));
    })
    .catch(makeCatch("ScreenShot ERROR"));
};

const makeCatch = msg => err => {
  console.log("Problem with " + msg, err);
  throw new Error(); // this is important- this rejects the Promise, so it stops the hardWork
};

const tryWork = () => {
  workHard().catch(error => {
    setInterval(tryWork, 5000);
  });
};

tryWork();
```

so...how do I call HardWork() all over again let's say in 5 minutes if I don't find what I need.

Comment: You're not using the results of any of the functions except `checkMagicButton`. That looks like a mistake. Is that your actual code, or psuedo-code? (can you post the actual code?)

Comment: Just use a setTimeout where that comment is

Comment: Also see how I chain the function results : ```takeAscreenShot()
    .then(pic => {some more code}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `async` functions already, and everything looks Promise-based already, so you can make `hardWork` `async` and then `await` each Promise inside of it. If final task fails, reject. In the caller of `hardWork`, if the Promise ultimately rejects, set a timeout to call it again in 5 minutes, otherwise you're done:

```
const hardWork = async () => {
  // I assume this next line was psuedo-code for an API call or something
  await `https:${screenshot.thumURL}`;

  const image = await downloadImage.downloadImage();
  await UploadToGcBucket.UploadToGcBucket(image);
  await timeout(5000);
  const button = await googleVisionAPI.findMagicButton(`some_screenshot.jpg`);
  if (button === -1) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  // success
};

const tryWork = () => {
  hardWork()
    .catch((error) => {
      setTimeout(tryWork, 5 * 60 * 1000); // 5 minutes
    });
};
tryWork();
```

If you need different error messages for the different possible errors, I'd make a higher-order function that you can pass into `.catch` that  logs the message, to keep the code DRY:

```
const makeCatch = msg => (err) => {
  console.log('Problem with ' + msg, err);
  throw new Error(); // this is important- this rejects the Promise, so it stops the hardWork
};

// ...

await downloadImage.downloadImage()
  .catch(makeCatch('downloadImage'));
await UploadToGcBucket.UploadToGcBucket(image)
  .catch(makeCatch('upload to gc'));
await timeout(5000);
const button = await googleVisionAPI.findMagicButton(`some_screenshot.jpg`)
  .catch(makeCatch('findButton'));
```

Live snippet:

```js
// dummied up API calls below...
const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const downloadImage = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
const uploadToGcBucket = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
// the below function will resolve to -1 70% of the time, and to 0 30% of the time
const findMagicButton = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200, Math.floor(Math.random() - 0.7)));
// dummied up API calls above...

const hardWork = async () => {
  const image = await downloadImage();
  await uploadToGcBucket(image);
  await timeout(500);
  const button = await findMagicButton(`some_screenshot.jpg`);
  if (button === -1) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  console.log('success');
};

const tryWork = () => {
  hardWork()
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('failure, retry');
      setTimeout(tryWork, 2 * 1000); // 2 seconds
    });
};
console.log('start');
tryWork();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately when I:
```
.then(button => {
                  if (button === -1) {
                    throw new Error();
                  }
                })
```
When you throw the new Error it actually doesn't .catch() on:
```
const tryWork = () => {
  workHard().catch(error => {
    setInterval(tryWork, 5000);
  });
};

tryWork();
```
but here:
``` .catch(makeCatch("AI finding button ERROR"));```

I have updated my code, so I think I would need to return something from workHard() function in order to catch it on the tryWork() function

Comment: Your current `workHard` function isn't chaining the long final Promise chain with its caller. Almost every time there's a Promise, it should either be the first Promise in its series, or it should be returned or `await`ed. So change to `return downloadScreenshot(...`, and `uploadToGCBucket()` to `return uploadToGCBucket()`, etc. Or, it would be much better to use the pattern in my answer - `await` each call, and the code is much cleaner (and less bug-prone)

Comment: Do you mind just putting a link to a code snippet in a much simpler code?
now I'm confused. 
I believe I used your pattern to catch errors in a higher-order function...

Comment: See snippet in edit. The `findMagicButton` results in it throwing 70% of the time, so it'll probably retry a few times before you see "Success".

Comment: You're a genius @CertainPerformance, I really appreciate all your awesome help!
It's flawlessly working now!